# Can an Indian national with an International Driving Permit rent a car in Spain / Portugal?

Tags: car-rentals, spain, driving-licenses, portugal

Also, is it possible to rent a car in Seville and drop it off in Algarve?

I'm traveling with a bunch of friends to Spain-Portugal, and we are planning to drive down the coast.

Comment: Why do you assume they cannot?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I guess the question could mean whether a foreign national is allowed to drive in the EU with an IDP.

Answer (score 1):

From [spain.info](http://www.spain.info/en/informacion-practica/consejos-viaje/consejos-practicos/conducir_en_espana/):

> What documentation is required to drive in Spain?
>
> You must be 18 year
> old:
>
> To drive in Spain you must be aged 18 or over. To rent a vehicle you
> must be 21 or over. Many companies also require you to have held your
> driver’s license for a minimum of one or two years. Remember that you
> will also require a credit card to rent a vehicle.
>
> A valid driver’s license:
>
> If you are the citizen of an EU member state, Switzerland, Norway,
> Iceland or Liechtenstein: you only require your valid driver’s
> license. If you are from another country you will require an
> International Driver’s License.
>
> Given that conditions may vary, we suggest that you contact the
> Spanish Embassy or Consulate to verify these requirements before you
> start your trip.

Comment: Note that the IDL is only a translation of a person's already-issued driver's license, and is not a driver's license in itself. The IDL is usually only required when the driver's license has non-Roman letters (as, for example,  a license from Japan). The IDL must be accompanied by the driver's already-issued regular driver's license.  The paragraph in @Burham's answer would be more accurate if it stated "If you are from another country, you will *also* require an International Driver's License."

Comment: I've heard it more often called IDP—Int'l Driving Permit.  And with no non-latin characters on my DL, car rental agencies never asked to see any IDP.  Also, even though the reservation said debit cards won't be accepted, I did use mine.

Answer (score 0):

If "Algarve" is Faro Algarve, Portugal, then yes, you can drop it off there.  Kayak and other aggregators and most car rental companies will let you search and find out if a particular drop-off point is possible.